# Aliexpress Dropshipper API Access Token is empty

Tags: php, aliexpress

We are attempting to get the Aliexpress dropship API working and have successfully created the authorisation_code but the access_token always returns empty.

It seems that with the move to the new API, AE have not updated many, if any docs and so it's almost guess work as to what's needed.

Has anyone had success with this?

Sample code from the php SDK we're using can be found below.

```
$appkey = 'app_key_goes_here';
$secret = 'app_secret_goes_here';
$code = @$_GET['code'];
require('ae-php-sdk/IopSdk.php');
echo $code;
if ($code) {
    generate_access_token_v2($code);
}

function generate_access_token_v2($code)
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $url = "https://api-sg.aliexpress.com/rest";
    $appkey = "app_key_goes_here";
    $appSecret = "app_secret_goes_here";
    $c = new IopClient($url, $appkey, $appSecret);
    $request = new IopRequest('/auth/token/create');
    $request->addApiParam('code', $code);
    var_dump($request);
    var_dump($c->execute($request));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing the following:

```
require('ae-php-sdk/IopSdk.php');
$appkey = "app_key_goes_here";
$appSecret = "app_secret_goes_here";
$url = "https://api-sg.aliexpress.com/rest";
$code = $_GET['code'];


$c = new IopClient($url,$appkey,$appSecret);
$request = new IopRequest('/auth/token/create');
$request->addApiParam('code',$code);

$results = $c->execute($request);
echo $results;
```

Comment: thanks, but now we get ""type":"ISV","code":"IncompleteSignature","message":"The request signature does not conform to platform standards"". We're using php8.0.  Did you encounter this too?

Comment: Change your URL to  $url = "https://api-sg.aliexpress.com/rest";

Comment: it still throws that error.